# Mascara de Android , Actua diferente segun API

Tags: java, android

Con 4.0.1 por ejemplo mi mascara la pone asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si yo pongo uno con version 6.0.0

me aparece de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi inquietud es porque aparece el signo de pesos al revez cuando mi version de android es menor mi codigo de la mascara es el siguiente

```
 public TextWatcher amount(final EditText editText) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        private String current = "";
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("["+getResources().getString(R.string.MonedaMonto)+",.]", "").replace(" ","");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString.replaceAll("\\s","").trim());
                // Obtienes la instancia del formateador
                DecimalFormat decimalFormat  = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

                // obtener la instancia del formatiador de simbolos
                DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

                // cambias el simbolo por US
                symbols.setCurrencySymbol(getResources().getString(R.string.MonedaMonto)+" ");

                // le asignamos el nuevo formateador de simbolo
                decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

                // formateamos
                String formatted = decimalFormat.format((parsed/100));

                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(formatted);
                editText.setSelection(formatted.length());

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Desde ya muchisimas gracias porque la verdad no me doy cuenta el porque de esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione al crear el

> DECIMAL FORMAT

Ejemplo

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat  = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
```

De esta forma la mascara actua de la misma forma siempre

Dejo el metodo completo

```
 public TextWatcher amount(final EditText editText) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        private String current = "";
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().equals(current) && s.toString().compareTo("")!=0){
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);


                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("["+getResources().getString(R.string.MonedaMonto)+",.]", "").replace(" ","");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString.replaceAll("\\s","").trim());
                // Obtienes la instancia del formateador

                DecimalFormat decimalFormat  = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);


                // obtener la instancia del formatiador de simbolos
                DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

                // cambias el simbolo por US
                symbols.setCurrencySymbol(getResources().getString(R.string.MonedaMonto)+" ");

                // le asignamos el nuevo formateador de simbolo
                decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

                // formateamos
                String formatted = decimalFormat.format((parsed/100));

                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(formatted);
                editText.setSelection(formatted.length());

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: eso se le dice localización o forzado de localización...

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/application-localization/

Comment: si programas oop lo mejor seria generar una libreria de localizacion que lea las posibles configuraciones desde un archivo xml, y que cargue la configuracion predeterminada del usuario en primera instancia segun lo desee el usuario...

Comment: Gracias por el aporte @FranciscoNúñez