# ¿Cómo puede crear un EditText personalizado para ingresar un monto?

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Como puedo crear un Edit Text para ingresar un monto de venta?,

Es su estado IDLE debe de mostrar $0.00 cuando se presione algún dígito en el teclado por ejemplo 1
se mostrará $0.01 cuando se presiona otro dígito por ejemplo 2 mostrará $0.12 y así sucesivamente hasta el monto sea ingresado.

Es decir para ingresar $12.00 se debe presionar la teclas 1,2,0,0,enter

¿Hay algun equivalente al UITextFielDelegate de android?

Comment: Rodolfo puedes revisar en el sitio antes de formular tu pregunta, tal vez lo que preguntas ya existe, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136363/mascara-de-android-actua-diferente-segun-api te sugiero realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask]  agregando preferentemente lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza esto

```
public TextWatcher amount(final EditText editText) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        private String current = "";
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().equals(current) && s.toString().compareTo("")!=0){
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("["+getResources().getString(R.string.MonedaMonto)+",.]", "").replace(" ","");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString.replaceAll("\\s","").trim());
                // Obtienes la instancia del formateador

                DecimalFormat decimalFormat  = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

                // obtener la instancia del formatiador de simbolos
                DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

                // cambias el simbolo por US
                symbols.setCurrencySymbol(getResources().getString(R.string.MonedaMonto)+" ");

                // le asignamos el nuevo formateador de simbolo
                decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
                // formateamos
                String formatted = decimalFormat.format((parsed/100));
                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(formatted);
                editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Para Agregarlo a tu caja

```
final EditText txtBillingMount =  findViewById(R.id.txtBillingMount);
txtBillingMount.addTextChangedListener(this.amount(txtBillingMount));
```

El recurso de Moneda es

```
<string name="MonedaMonto">$</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta librería que te ayuda a dar formato a los números que ingreses en un EditText,  en el enlace esta el repositorio en gitHub y su forma de uso [Repositorio GitHub](https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext)

Lo primero que hay que hacer es agregar lo siguiente al modulo app de Gradle;

```
implementation 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.4'
```

Y declarar en el archivo xml de la actividad 

`<com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
                android:id="@+id/masked_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:mask="$ **.**"
                app:notMaskedSymbol="*"
                app:maskIconColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                />`

Revisa el repositorio, hay varios ejemplos de las diferentes formas en las que puedes darle formato al texto